# Android SDK is not property installed on VS 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install Android on Visual Studio 2017 Professional. When installation is complete I go to Tools - Options - Xamarin and see that there is an issue with Android SDK:
[image: Android SDK error]

When hovering over red icon the error message is: 'Cannot find adb.exe in specified SDK path'.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Where have you installed the Android SDK? If it is located on a different path, you just need to edit the `Android SDK Location` to point to the actual location of the SDK

Comment: try placing the specifc location of adb.exe instand the root SDK directory.

Comment: This is VS installer that installed Android SDK at this path. I verified this path and sdk is actually there but adb.exe is missing.

Comment: @SimonD is there a platform-tools folder there? adb executable should be there

Comment: @Cris There a 'platforms' folder but it's empty. Any other of folders do not contain adb exe either. Looks like VS installer didn't install it at all but why, I got no errors while installation.

Comment: @SimonD I guess you can always download platform-tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and copy them to the required folder

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, I would recommend running a repair installation and making sure it completes without issues.

If you file a ticket directly from VS, we can take a look at your logs and see if the install failed to complete for some reason. It seems to me like you are missing a component.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I rerun VS 2017 installation in change mode but it didn't help, I still have the same error like on the screenshot above. How can I file a ticket from VS?